# assignment of coordinates to an FEA element

Tags: c

I need some help to match data in efficient way...

Here is my problem:
From a file I read in some elements, which have an ID related to an another entry (node) which have the XYZ-coordinates.

It looks like this (every field is separated by blanks, so the entries are Field0 [blank] Field1 [blank] and so on)

ELEMENT 1 24

ELEMENT 2 89

ELEMENT 11 123

NODE 24 0.1 3.5 45.6

NODE 89 2.5 23.8 4.9

NODE 123 11.4 3.7 5.7

So what I did in the past is to read in the elements in the same order as they occur. For the nodes I allocated an array with the same size as the maximum number of node IDs that can occur and put the XYZ-coordinates under the index of the node ID:

```
if (strstr(Field0,"ELEMENT") ){
  Elem[NumElem].ID  = atoi(Field1);
  Elem[NumElem].NID = atoi(Field2);
  NumElem++;
}

if (strstr(Field0,"NODE") ){
               Index = atoi(Field1);
  Node[Index].ID     = Index       ;
  Node[Index].XYZ[0] = atof(Field2);
  Node[Index].XYZ[1] = atof(Field3);
  Node[Index].XYZ[2] = atof(Field4);
}    

for (i=0;i<NumElem;i++){
  Elem[i].Coord[0] = Node[ Elem[i].NID ].XYZ[0];
  Elem[i].Coord[1] = Node[ Elem[i].NID ].XYZ[1];
  Elem[i].Coord[2] = Node[ Elem[i].NID ].XYZ[2];
}
```

(hoping the snippet has no errors, because I had to remove some entries to make it more readable for others)

After that I freed Node and have all data stored in the struct Elem.

The way above is only valid if all node IDs are unique within the whole data.

Now the data can be split into several files. In each file the IDs are unique but for the whole set of data they are not. 
So the example above can occur multiple times in different files with the same element and node IDs, but they are NOT the same or identical entries since the coordinates may be different.

For some other reasons I can not parse the whole data set file by file to put the data into the struct described above.

Of course I can go the brute force way by nesting some for-loops to check for every element in the file ID and the node ID and then looping over the whole node entries to find the matching data, but this will be very slow...

Does anyone have any hints on how to solve this problem?

Comment: When you say **i can not parse the whole data set file by file to put the data into the struct described above.** -- What happens? Sample data file data, and sample of what you get that is causing the problem would help. Nothing jumps out above other than `XYZ[0-2]` for `X`, `Y`, and `Z` being a bit confusing.

Comment: I inserted a small example and correted (hopefully) the code... It is just to make clear that i can jump directly to the entry in the node array without any loop. The function to parse the whole data set is more ore less done, so for this version i am not able to change anything in the parser to match the data file by file

Comment: I think you missed the problem. The code is running properly. as long as every node ID is unique there will be a unique match. Since node IDs can be occur multiple times (with different coordinates) the algorithm will not work. I will get only the coordinates of the last node with the same ID found in the data set. Now i need to check not only fpr the node ID but also for the file ID and for this a direct assignment (as made in the example code) is not possible. So my question is having an algorithm which is faster then the brute force method looping over all element and node entries.